# How can I compare a profile that is Sandbox with the one in Prod to see where if there were changes

Tags: profile

What is the best to compare one profile that is currently in Sandbox and Production to see if there is a change and where is the change exactly? I am open to even exporting them in excel to compare.

Comment: Try https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/ to compare profiles within same org. For different orgs, you can extract the metadata of profiles and compare them with an [editor](https://text-compare.com/).
Sample package.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Int-Account Management</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare profile between two orgs as per salesforce standard functionality.  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVxtUAF/need-to-compare-differences-between-sandbox-and-production?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null).

However, you can check below third party tools to compare profiles, permission sets and FLS between any two Salesforce orgs.

1. [Bluecanvas](https://tools.bluecanvas.io/perms/)
2. [Toolsforce](https://toolsforce.net/)
3. [Salesforce Org Compare](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcqksUAB)
4. [Security Zen](https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: We use SFDX for this from time to time as well.